# How can I trigger Pi Camera to take time lapse photos every day at sunrise?

Tags: python, camera

I'm interested in capturing a time lapse photo sequence every morning at sunrise.

I'm able to get the exact sunrise time using a Python script into a variable, but not sure how to go about setting the time trigger for the camera.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest might be to create a delayed job each day from your python script. You can install the `at` command for one-shot jobs like this if the time varies each day (`sudo apt-get install at`). One plus to this approach is that you could have your python script schedule several days' worth of captures in one go rather than checking each day.

Alternately, you could have your python script just idle and call the `raspistill` executable at the appropriate time. If you prefer to control the camera directly, you can use something like [picamera](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/picamera/1.10). I used this to run a timelapse sequence over several months.